# How to display a image from src folder in react app with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to display many images from my src folder in local react app on a component with axios but i don't know what i have to do to works. If i need to use node.js to do that, show me how please.

Axios code:

I would have to back 3 folders to get in src folder, from this component.

`async componentDidMount() { const response = await Axios.get('src/image/'); }`

React component's code:

And to show this images i'm using react-slick to render a banner.

`<Slider { ...settings }> { response.map((image) => { return ( <img key="" src={image} /> ) })} </Slider>`

Comment: Donot keep images in react app src folder. You should load the image URLs from the server. In nodejs server you have to add app.use(express.static('public')) https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html if you are using express.

Comment: Create an /public folder in server app and add the images there. So you can directly access the images as server_url/image1.png

Comment: @NisugaJayawardana I didn't understand, and with this can i return an image array to display them?

Comment: Hi @William Pedro. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Yes you can return an array (Ex: [ 'img_url1, 'img_url2']) as the response